# Dropbox error - 'echo 100000 | sudo tee / proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches'

Tags: directory, system, dropbox, error-handling, monitoring

Dropbox gives me an error that mentions echo tee 100000 but then it disappears.
How to fix or remove msg?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file with your favourite text editor, e.g. `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and append (or modify the value of) `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000` at the end of the file as a new line.

As an option you can use the command `sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000` or the command below, as described on the Dropbox help guide, the results will be the same.

---

[`From the advanced help guide from Dropbox`](https://www.dropbox.com/help/145)

> Monitoring more than 10000 folders
>
> The Linux version of the Dropbox desktop application is limited from monitoring more than 10000 folders by default. Anything over that is not watched and, therefore, ignored when syncing. There's an easy fix for this. Open a terminal and enter the following:
>
> `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p`
>
> This command will tell your system to watch up to 100000 folders. Once the command is entered and you enter your password, Dropbox will immediately resume syncing.

Answer (score 17):

With Ubuntu 13.04:

```
$ sudo nano /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Then change what is in the file (I had 8192) to 100000

Then "ctrl o" to save and "ctrl x" to exit

Then run:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

then restart Dropbox.

Comment: This one works with the newer Ubuntu releases!

Comment: this won't change it permanently... just for the current boot

Comment: In Ubuntu 14 this results in Fsync errors.

Answer (score 7):

Editing `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` directly results in Fsync errors in GVIM.  This is because you can't really modify those files directly.  Instead, it is better to use this command:

`sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000`

This doesn't cause file editing problems, and to me, looks like a more proper method.

Comment: Does this save the configuration when you reboot?

Comment: @Malcolm It hasn't ever prompted me to set max_user_watches again.

Comment: That's odd. Using the `sysctl -w` method causes Dropbox to prompt me again every time I reboot. Only adding the line to `/etc/sysctl.conf` fixed it permanently for me. I'm using Debian Jessie.

Comment: This is the easiest answer if you get fsync errors.

Comment: You need to edit sysctl.conf as shown in the answer to make changes persistent.