# How can I tell if I am out of inotify watches?

Tags: kernel, files, inotify

I use an application that consumes inotify watches. I've [already set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535768/what-is-a-reasonable-amount-of-inotify-watches-with-linux)

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=32768
```

in `/etc/sysctl.conf` but last night the application stopped indexing unless I ran it manually, which leads me to suspect I am out of watches.

Since I don't know what the trade off is when I increase this number (does it consume more RAM?), I don't know if I should just increase this number, so I'd like to know if there's a way I can tell if it's using all these watches and what the tradeoffs might be for increasing it.

Comment: This question has become quite relevant again as it turns out in 18.04 unlocking the screen is not possible if one has run out of inode watches.

Comment: It would be possible to see the number of inotify watches in use if the kernel patch I linked here got merged:
https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues/866#issuecomment-1136379569

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### How do you know if you are out of watches? *tail* will tell!

- Start `tail` with the `-f` (follow) option on any old file, e.g. `tail -f /var/log/dmesg`:

  - If all is well, it will show the last 10 lines and pause; abort with Ctrl-C
  - If **you are out of watches**, it will fail with this [somewhat cryptic error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils/+bug/700958):

    ```
    tail: cannot watch '/var/log/dmsg': No space left on device
    ```

**For the curious: Why is *tail* a "telltail"?**

- Actually, *any* [well-written app](http://web.archive.org/web/20110220003614/http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=33193) should have the courtesy of telling you, since the *inotify* API/calls clearly tells them what the deal is.
- Try `strace tail -f ...` instead, and when it succeeds, it ends with:

  ```
  inotify_add_watch(4, "/var/log/dmesg", IN_MODIFY...) = 1
  ```
- but if it fails, i.e. *you are out of watches*, it'll say:

  ```
  inotify_add_watch(4, "/var/log/dmesg", IN_MODIFY..)
  = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
  ```

### Can you increase the watches? By how much? Any tradeoffs?

**Short answer:** Sure, no sweat. Go to straight to a half-million (524288) if you want...the additional memory used *should be* negligible on a modern system with 4GB+ of memory.

- Each *used* inotify watch takes up 540 bytes (32-bit system), or 1 kB (double - on 64-bit) [sources: [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/lsyncd/KZfQE9VUZFw/twTMjxWa41wJ), [2](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F535768%2Fwhat-is-a-reasonable-amount-of-inotify-watches-with-linux&ei=Ly7nT8DrHOfM2gWI3MXZCQ&usg=AFQjCNF_NXKrn31FqzHM0V0L1exi8CneOA)]
- This comes out of *kernel memory*, which is unswappable.
- So, assuming you set the max at 524288, and all were used (improbable), you'd be using approx. 256MB/512MB of 32-bit/64-bit kernel memory

  - Note that your application will also use additional memory to keep track of the inotify handles, file/directory paths, etc. -- how much depends on its design.
- What's the max value? I guess none, in theory, as long as you have enough RAM. In practice, 524288 [has been officially recommended by apps](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers), and people have been [setting it to *2 million*](http://groups.google.com/group/lsyncd/browse_thread/thread/e79f8e46897693e7), with the accompanying memory usage, of course.

Comment: If you also want to know the actual current number of inotify watches (thus more then yes/no), go for `sudo lsof | grep -i inotify | wc -l`

Comment: "well-written-app" link broken.

Comment: @FrankNocke You might want to be a little more careful with your grep. That can catch many things that aren't an inotify watch. For instance, if you have a file open named "inotify.txt", it'll count that. In fact, on my system, this seems to catch two distinct types of lines: ones whose NAME (last column) is `inotify`, and ones whose TASKCMD (4th column) is `inotify_reader`. I'm not sure which of those two is an actual inotify watch.

Answer (score 15):

### I don't know if I should just increase this number

The easy way of checking if you reached your `max_user_watches` value is, with your user, to use `inotifywatch`, from the package `inotify-tools`, and check if you can still collect information from a file.

For example `inotifywatch -v /home/bruno/.profile` for me returns:

```
Establishing watches...
Total of 1 watches.
Finished establishing watches, now collecting statistics.
```

So `inotify` has no issues creating a new watch, no issues here.

If you have reached your maximum limit in inotify watches it will return something like

```
Failed to watch /home/bruno/.profile; upper limit on inotify watches reached!
```

If you see something like this then you have reached the limit and will need to increase the allowed watches limit.

### Does it consume more RAM?

Yes, it does. But according to this [old article](http://kerneltrap.org/node/3847) the amount it consumes is minimal compared with other aspects of a running desktop.

> --MEMORY USAGE--
>
> The inotify data structures are light weight:
>
> inotify watch is 40 bytes
>   inotify device is 68 bytes
>   inotify event is 272 bytes
>
> So assuming a device has 8192 watches, the structures are only going
>   to consume 320KB of memory. With a maximum number of 8 devices allowed
>   to exist at a time, this is still only 2.5 MB
>
> Each device can also have 256 events queued at a time, which sums to
>   68KB per device. And only .5 MB if all devices are opened and have
>   a full event queue.
>
> So approximately 3 MB of memory are used in the rare case of 
>   everything open and full.
>
> Each inotify watch pins the inode of a directory/file in memory,
>   the size of an inode is different per file system but lets assume
>   that it is 512 byes.
>
> So assuming the maximum number of global watches are active, this would
>   pin down 32 MB of inodes in the inode cache. Again not a problem
>   on a modern system.

I am of course assuming things did not change a lot since the article was written but  looking at the numbers I would not worry and increasing the limit will not increase RAM consumption by much.

---

### Related posts about `inotify`

- [Dropbox error - 'echo 100000 | sudo tee / proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148171/echo-100000-sudo-tee-proc-sys-fs-inotify-max-user-watches-error-on-dropbox/148177#148177)
- [kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13751/kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached)

Comment: Sorry man, I had a draft open yesterday for a few hours and didn't see your answer before I posted mine. I guess it's OK since they have two different approaches :-)  Could you just clarify that in recent kernels, inotify uses 0.5KB (on 32-bit) or 1KB (64-bit) of kernel memory per watch, since the old info from 2005 doesn't seem to be true any longer?