# Evince is no longer auto-reloading documents. How can I troubleshoot this?

Tags: latex, evince, inotify

Evince (the pdf viewer) used to reload my .pdf files after I compiled them in LaTeX. However, this behavior has recently stopped to the point where I have to manually reload Evince (control + R) to show changes. I have tried resetting the desktop environment (i.e. reboot) but this doesn't help.

Any ideas on how I can go about troubleshooting this? My Googling has given me the vague awareness that Evince depends on other services (inotify?) for this feature, but I am not sure how I can go about diagnosing what the problem is precisely.

Comment: System, version, etc? I have 14.04 on three different computers and it does not show the problem. Yes, it depends on inotify, but that should work out of the box on all Ubuntus.

Comment: This is still 12.04. I have tried upgrading evince to it's latest version (i.e. newer than on the repository) through a .deb file, and this hasn't helped. I have another 12.04 installation on a different machine for which this behavior works perfectly. Also, it used to work on this machine, but has recently stopped. For a time it would stop working on-and-off, but now it never works.

Comment: You could be running out of inotify watches. Checkout [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148171/dropbox-error-echo-100000-sudo-tee-proc-sys-fs-inotify-max-user-watches/148177#148177) and the ensuing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luis' suggestion worked. I used the following command:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p
```

as suggested by the question he linked to, which was addressing Dropbox syncing.

Comment: I used the mentioned command but not worked. I use `pdflatex examplefile.tex` to create pdf file. Is anything needed to view changes?

Comment: This is not really an answer?

Answer (score 1):

A completely different reason why this problem might happen: Evince (as well as Atril) won't auto-reload a document that has been opened *via a symlink*.

```bsh
$ ln -s example.pdf link-to-example.pdf
$ evince link-to-example.pdf
```

At this point, changing `example.pdf` will not trigger a reload in Evince, as it would if you had directly opened the file as `evince example.pdf`. (The idea seems to be that the “file I've opened”, i.e. the symlink, has *not* in fact changed.)

Short of manually looking up the link location, one way to circumvent this issue is to have Bash do it on the command line:

```
$ evince $(readlink link-to-example.pdf)
```

or more generally

```
$ evince $(realpath link-to-example.pdf)
```